# erase max element from STL set

Tags: c++, stl, set

This is a follow-up on a previous question I had ( [Complexity of STL max_element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313301/complexity-of-stl-max-element) ).

I want to basically pop the max element from a set, but I am running into problems.

Here is roughly my code:

```
set<Object> objectSet;

Object pop_max_element() {
    Object obj = *objectSet.rbegin();
    set<Object>::iterator i = objectSet.end()--; //this seems terrible
    objectSet.erase(i); //*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer
    return obj;
}
```

Earlier I tried `objectSet.erase(objectSet.rbegin());` but the compiler complained that there was no matching function (I'm guessing it doesn't like the reverse_iterator). I know there is no checking for an empty set, but it's failing when objectSet.size() >> 0.

Comment: `*objectSet.rbegin();` is that a typo? you're dereferencing the set?

Comment: No, it's the iterator being dereferenced. The dot binds tighter than the star.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you're trying to do a little too much in that iterator assignment. You're applying the *post-decrement* operator to whatever `end` returns. I'm not really sure what that does, but it's almost certainly not what you want. Assign the result of `end` to `i`, and *then* decrement it to get the last element of the set.

```
set<Object>::iterator i = objectSet.end();
--i;
Object obj = *i;
objectSet.erase(i);
return obj;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this:

```
set<Object> objectSet;

Object pop_max_element() {
    Object obj = *objectSet.rbegin();
    set<Object>::iterator i = --objectSet.end(); // NOTE: Predecrement; not postdecrement.
    objectSet.erase(i); //*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
set<Object>::iterator i = objectSet.end()--;
```

means 'assign end() to i then decrement a temporary variable that is about to be thrown away'.  In other words it's the same as `set<Object>::iterator i = objectSet.end();`, and I'm sure you recognise you cannot erase end(), because it points to one past the end.  Use something like this instead:

```
assert(!objectSet.empty()); // check there is something before end
set<Object>::iterator i = objectSet.end();
--i;
objectSet.erase(i);
```

and that's okay, it's a legitimate way to essentially reproduce `.back()` for a set.

Also, reverse iterators have a `base()` member to convert to a normal iterator and I guess you can only erase normal iterators - try `objectSet.erase(objectSet.rbegin().base())`.

Comment: I did try the rbegin().base(), to no avail.

Comment: `rbegin().base()` is the same as `end()`.